# nginx map variable cannot as upstream hash key?

Tags: nginx

I want to use part of uri as upstream hash key, the config like follows:

```
map $uri $dir {
     ~^/(.*?)/ $1;
}

upstream backServer {
    server 172.10.27.223:80;
    server 172.10.27.161:80;
    hash $dir consistent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backServer;
    }
}
```

But this is not effect, the request only send to the first server, regardless of the uri.
And I also try the hash like **hash $dir consistent** , that config is effect right.

How can I config the nignx?

Comment: How many different URI's did you try?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a couple of errors in your config, since this works:

```
map $uri $hashtest {
  "~^(.*)/" "$1";
}

upstream nodeServers {
   server 192.168.1.3:8888;
   server 192.168.1.3:8889;
   hash $hashtest consistent;
}

server {
    ...
    location /xyz/ {
        proxy_pass http://nodeServers/;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```